# Python Selenium instagram bot, getting the list of followers

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, instagram

I am trying to get followers list of specified account but when i open followers popup everything is okay except sometimes the program clicks randomly people's account and then program crashes.

I searched a lot, they talk about structure of the instagram. I saw a comment like instagram changes it's element during the session so beacuse of that my program clicks wrong element but i showed the way with xpath. 
some people says, ajax causes this, I am trying to figure this out for 2 or 3 days and i am exhausted.
I will leave my code's getting list part below if you are interested.

```
def get_followers(self,target):
    #GOING TARGETS URL
    self.driver.get(f"{self.url}/{target}/")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    dialog=self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.isgrP ul')
    #dialog=self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pbNvD.fPMEg.HYpXt ul')
    #folC= len(dialog.find_elements_by_css_selector("li"))

    action = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
    fc=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text

    down=0
    for x in range(1,math.ceil(int(fc)/12)):
        if down!=math.ceil(int(fc)/12):
            print(down,math.ceil(int(fc)/12))
            down+=1
            dialog.click()
            action.key_down(Keys.END).key_up(Keys.END).perform()
            time.sleep(0.4)

    flist=self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pbNvD.fPMEg.HYpXt a")
    print(flist)

    #followers=dialog.find_elements_by_css_selector("li a")
    for follower in flist:
        print(follower.text)
```

I think the problem is ***HERE !!***

```
action = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
#HOW MANY FOLLOWERS TARGET HAVE ? FOR EX 548
fc=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text

down=0
#SCROLLING DOWN TO THE BOTTOM
for x in range(1,math.ceil(int(fc)/12)):
    if down!=math.ceil(int(fc)/12):
        print(down,math.ceil(int(fc)/12))
        down+=1
        dialog.click()
        action.key_down(Keys.END).key_up(Keys.END).perform()
        time.sleep(0.4)
 # AFTER FINISHING, GETTING ALL LIST ELEMENTS ASS YOU CAN SEE ON THE CODE UP THERE
 # BUT WHEN IT SCROLLS IT CLICKS SOMEONE'S PROFILE AND GOES THERE
 # BECAUSE OF THAT PROGRAM CRASHES
```